# How to generate the Sum with percentage...?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to perform an Calculations in a Table , some how it's not working , same script is working fine http://www.jquerycookbook.com/demos/S3-TablesTabsPanels/26-TableCalculateTotal.html

Please help me with some tips

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/28zchg9s/2/)

```
  $(function () {
        $('.pnm, .price, .subtot, .grdtot').prop('readonly', true);
        var $tblrows = $("#tblProducts tbody tr");

        $tblrows.each(function (index) {
            var $tblrow = $(this);

            $tblrow.find('.qty').on('change', function () {

                var qty = $tblrow.find("[name=qty]").val();
                var price = $tblrow.find("[name=price]").val();
                var subTotal = parseInt(qty, 10) * parseFloat(price);

                if (!isNaN(subTotal)) {

                    $tblrow.find('.subtot').val(subTotal.toFixed(2));
                    var grandTotal = 0;

                    $(".subtot").each(function () {
                        var stval = parseFloat($(this).val());
                        grandTotal += isNaN(stval) ? 0 : stval;
                    });

                    $('.grdtot').val(grandTotal.toFixed(2));
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: add jquery reference. that causes the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open chrome dev tools and it says:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Which means, you have not added a reference to jquery in your fiddle.

To add a reference to any framework on jsfiddle,

Click on the Javascript *setting* icon -> FRAMEWORKS & EXTENSIONS -> Select the framework and version (in your case, jQuery)

Here's an updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/28zchg9s/3/)

If you were to face this issue while working locally on your editor, add this in your HTML.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, why other two fields are not working ...GST% and Total
var $price      = $("input[name='subtot']"),
    $percentage = $("input[name='gst']").on("input", calculatePrice),
    $total   = $("input[name='total']").on("input", calculatePerc);
    

function calculatePrice() {
    var percentage = $(this).val();
    var price      = $price.val();
    var calcPrice  = (price + ( price * percentage / 100 )).toFixed(2);
    $total.val( calcPrice );
}

function calculatePerc() {
    var total = $(this).val();
    var price    = $price.val();

Comment: @Kiku in your `calculatePrice()` function you have a missing "+" sign after price. Also you need to parse the value. Change it to:`function calculatePrice() {
    var percentage = $(this).val();
    var price      = parseFloat($price.val());
    var calcPrice  = (price + ( price * percentage / 100 )).toFixed(2);
    $total.val( calcPrice );
}`

Comment: I have added "+" but still not able to generate the output 
https://jsfiddle.net/28zchg9s/6/

Comment: @Kiku I updated the comment. You need to have `var price = parseFloat($price.val())`

Comment: @Kiku i just tested this and it is updating **all** the row totals. It is because of this line:  `$total.val( calcPrice );`...   `$total` has all the inputs with class `.total`. So what you need to do is update the `input` with `.total` class for **that** row: Check it https://jsfiddle.net/adigas/28zchg9s/7/

Comment: First row is working fine, rest of the rows showing incorrect numbers

Comment: @Kiku that's because of this bugger: `var price = parseFloat($price.val())` Test it now https://jsfiddle.net/adigas/28zchg9s/8/

Comment: @Kiku you'll have to fix `calculatePerc()` on similar logic